# what is the date format of this string?

Tags: java, string, date, gson, simpledateformat

I want to parse this json string into date

"startDateTime":"2014-08-10T20:08:45.0218Z"

and then parse it to another date format.

I thought using this:

`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd/MM HH:mm ???").create;`

but I'm not sure how what is the format of "2014-08-10T20:08:45.0218Z"

is it `yyyy-mm-dd ???`

Comment: That's an XML date format ...

Comment: Just the Date part? Or the entire String?

Answer (score 2):

> 2014-08-10T20:08:45.0218Z

This looks like an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date

> Date and time expressed according to ISO 8601:
>   
> Combined date and time in UTC: ... 2014-08-20T19:23:25Z

so

> [`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18217193/20394)

should do it.

Joda time also provides `ISODateTimeFormat` since this is a common format.

Comment: Joda time? built in lib in java?

Comment: @user1065869, Joda time is a decent date/time library that many (myself included) prefer to Java's horribly broken `java.util.{Data,Calendar}` APIs.  See the [docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html).  [Java 8](http://java.dzone.com/articles/introducing-new-date-and-time) may get a significantly revamped date/time core library based in part on Joda time.

Comment: thanks. I'll read about it. Can you please see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449502/gsonbuilder-setdateformat-doesnt-change-the-string-that-i-get-from-the-s maybe I the date format doesn't fit?

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
String date = sdf.format(new Date());
System.out.println(date);
Date d = sdf.parse(date);
```